# Why can not send sending continuously through “I2Cdrv->MasterReceive（）”in CMSIS_DRIVER IIC using at24c02?

Tags: eeprom, cmsis

I have finished IIC driver through CMSIS_DRIVER using at24c02. But I can not transfer bytes continuously. After inserting the "Hal_delay", it works. Why?
[image]

Who used, give me the answer please.